# Pandas replace column values by condition with averages based on a value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, preprocessing

I have a dataframe with people's CV data.
Among others, there's a column with years of experience, and a column with age.
Some people stated their age and experience in a way that **experience > age**. For example `age=30` and `experience=40`, which is a problem.

I am trying to perform a following task:
If `experience > age`, replace the value of `experience` with an average experience of people of the same `age`. For example if `age=30` and `experience=40`, replace `experience` with an average experience of all 30-year olds.

The problem is that I don't know how to obtain the age of a specific person in the slice `df[df['experience'] > df['age']]`.

AFAIK it could be done by something like this:

```
mask = (df['experience'] > df['age'])

df['experience_cleaned'] = np.where(mask, df[df['age'] == age]['experience'].mean() ,df['experience'])
```

I would appreciate if you show me how it can be done, because I could use the technique to also preprocess more data in a similar way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get a dictionary with average age where experience < age

```
mapping = df[df['age']>df['experience']].groupby('age').mean().apply(list).to_dict()['experience']
```

2. Use this dictionary to replace values where experience > age

```
df.loc[df['age']<df['experience'],'experience'] = df[df['age']<df['experience']]['age'].map(mapping)
```